# how to use same environement varibale in multiple steps in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Below script giving an error
**The deployment environment 'staging' in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml file occurs multiple times in the pipeline. Please refer to our documentation for valid environments and their ordering.**

```
image: python:3.8

options:
  docker: true
  
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
    - step:
        deployment: staging
        name: Setup stage
        script:
          - echo ${db_name}
    - step:
        deployment: staging
        name: Setup cli prod
        script:
          - echo ${db_name}
    - step:
        deployment: staging
        name: Setup cli sandbox
        script:
          - echo ${db_name}
```

I want to use same environment variable (staging) in all steps of my pipeline. Please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done because steps marked as deployments must be unique.

Deployment variables are those needed to deploy the VCS to a particular deployment stage. If you are setting up administrative tasks as pipelines, those are NOT deployments.

Or if those are actual deployments, abide by the error message you are getting and make sure the declared deployment stage is unique:

```
image: python:3.8

options:
  docker: true
  
definitions:
  yaml-anchors:
    - &deploy-step
        script:
          - echo ${db_name}

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
    - step:
        <<: *deploy-step
        deployment: staging
        name: Deploy staging
    - step:
        <<: *deploy-step
        deployment: production
        name: Deploy prod
    - step:
        deployment: sandbox
        name: Deploy sandbox
```

Comment: Its already in jira for implement in bitbucket. I have solve this using repository variables rather than deployment variables. Thanks for your suggestion.